# How to write HTML, CSS and Javascript all together in Joomla 2.5 article?

Tags: javascript, html, css, joomla2.5

I am trying to write HTML, CSS and Javascript all together in joomla 2.5 article but I am failed to get desired output, Is there any way to work this all 3 together in joomla 2.5 article?

Please Help me Out with this issue. I am new to Joomla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extension called [Sourcerer](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer) which will allow you to adding code into articles.

Once installed, enable the plugin, then open you articles and you can start adding your code into the article. Below is an example:

```
{source}

<span style="color:red">This text should be red!</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("This is Javascript");
</script>

<?php
    echo 'This is PHP';
?>
{/source}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: okay it working in 2.5 thanks for the solution but i am facing same problem for my one site which is built on joomla 1.5 any solution for that?

Comment: @AnandMehta - You can use the last supported version they developed for Joomla 1.5 - http://download.nonumber.nl/?ext=sourcerer&v=3.3.0